# Apache listen on 2 ports for same SSL virtual host

Tags: apache, ssl

I have an issue where an external site is requesting data from an internal server using port 444 which my firewall translates to 443.

The problem is, my internal clients don't get a response from the internal server when they make a request on 444 as there is no firewall in the way to forward the port to 443.

I want to make the apache server listen on both 443 and 444 ports but I have zero Ubuntu/apache experience, and have no documentation on how the server was configured, so I've hit a bit of a wall.

I can access the `ports.conf` file and it looks like this:

```
#
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
\#
```

Then there is the file `/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` that "points" at `../sites-available/default-ssl.conf`, and it looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin it@oursite.com
ServerName web.oursite.com
ServerAlias web.outsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
...
```

followed by a bit of SSL certificate stuff and other directory stuff

`apache2.conf` doesn't seem to have anything non-default in it

Could anyone help me with what I need to add to the `ports.conf` file and/or the `default-ssl.conf` file?

Answer (score 5):

Basically with the `Listen` directive and then the virtual host can use two ports too:

```
Listen 443
Listen 444
```

and then:

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:444>
     #rest of the virtualhost config here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: THANKS! it worked! but now i need some kind of DNS entry so the external domain name web.oursite.com will resolve to the local ip 10.0.0.50 any ideas? A new forward lookup zone?

Comment: DNS is out of the scope of your own question, open another one

Comment: Works perfect!

I just have tried <If "%{SERVER_PORT} == '443'">: in Apache/2.4.41 and got a "SSLEngine not allowed in <If> context" message, so don't waste time.